# issue with validating non required input with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Using JQuery, I want to validate non required input field if input field value exists.

value allow null in DB

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="moms_md_name" id="moms_md_name" value="">
```

**Using JQuery**

```
var mom_maiden_name = $('#moms_md_name').val();
```

**1rst try**

```
// …
} else if (maiden_name !== '' && maiden_name !== null) {
  if (!maiden_name.match(/^(?=.*[a-z]).{3,20}$/)) {
    alert("Mother maiden name not properly entered!");
  }
// …
```

Now when I:

- Leave the field blank/empty, it works and I get result
- Disable JQuery validation I get result too
- Enter a wrong input like `222` or `aa`, I get error message
- Enter a correct input, I get no result at all <- ?

**2nd try**

```
// …
 } else if(maiden_name !== '' && maiden_name !== null){
   if (
      $('#moms_md_name').val()
      && !mom_maiden_name.match(/^(?=.*[a-z]).{3,20}$/)) {
          alert("Mother maiden name not properly entered!");
   }
// …
```

Now when I:

- Leave the field blank/empty, it works and I get result
- Disable JQuery validation I get result too
- Enter a wrong input like `222` or `aa`, I get error message
- Enter a correct input, I get no result at all <- ?

**PHP** - looking for something equivalent of below (disable for testing)

```
// …
else if(!empty($_POST['moms_md_name'])) {
  if (
    isset($_POST['moms_md_name'])
    && !preg_match('%^[A-Za-z\.\' \-]{2,30}$%', $_POST['moms_md_name'])
    ) {
        echo "Mother maiden name need to be properly entered!";
        exit();
    }
}
// …
```

Specifying a valid value gives no message/console log.
Though it works if I disable JQuery and enable PHP validation.

Comment: Heavy grammar and formatting lifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll begin with your Javascript code:

```
    else if (maiden_name !== '' && maiden_name !== null) {
      if (!maiden_name.match(/^(?=.*[a-z]).{3,20}$/)) {
         alert("Mother maiden name not properly entered!");
   }
```

First you should verify if the value is empty then do your code:

```
var mom_maiden_name = $('#moms_md_name').val();
if (mom_maiden_name  == '' || mom_maiden_name.match(/^(?=.*[a-z]).{3,20}$/)) {
    //Validation passed 
} else {
    //Validation failed again
}
```

I'm not sure what the regex should do but I assume it's correct.

Second, looking at your PHP code, I see a wrong validation there. If you first check a value for not being empty, you can automatically be assured that it's set. If you want to keep your code, you should invert those 2 conditions in 'if' :

```
if(isset($_POST['moms_md_name'])) {
   if (!empty($_POST['moms_md_name']) && !preg_match('%^[A-Za-z\.\' \-]{2,30}$%', $_POST['moms_md_name'])) {
      echo "Mother maiden name need to be properly entered!";
      exit();
   }
}
```

Again, I don't know what the regex does so I will assume it's correct.

Comment: I want to be able to let the field blank while sending it, using your php/jquery - I get error msg when field is blank tell me that the field is missing value

Comment: i Edited the code, I'm sorry I didn't see you  accept empty values.

Comment: php shouid be !empty && !preg_match, if not, i still get error when blank